# Setting div height based on its width

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to dynamically set a divs width, then set its height to a certain percentage of that width. Something like this:

```
#myDiv{
    width:%100;
    height: {35% of width};
}
```

I want to retain the ratio of the width to height of a div regardless of what the width may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='box'> 
    <div class='content'>All your content are belong to us</div> 
</div>
```

We use two block elements to achieve the desired behaviour, box for width, content for height.

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;     /* desired width */
}
.box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /*What you want the height to be in relation to the width*/
}
```

**The Content:**
Then set the content to cover the entire box absolutely so no matter the size, it fits!

```
.content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Tada you are done...

SOURCE: [Pure CSS](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)

Comment: My answer was pure CSS as well and posted before yours, so not sure why you stated...."or"

Comment: My Apologies, your answer wasn't there as I begun typing and I didnt do a check before hitting the button. Will change that "Or" now.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with CSS by setting the height to zero and then adding a percentage to padding-bottom.  You might have to tweak it a little to get the desired outcome but here's a fiddle with an example
http://jsfiddle.net/wbq8o3s7/

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 35%;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Simple semantics my dear Watson :)  The padding actually becomes the height of the div and as the screen size changes so does the padding.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get it. What exactly is the 35% calculated on, and why? Normally a height-related percentage would be calculated based on a height? Why is it calculated on a width here?

Comment: A percentage value on top/bottom padding or margin is relative to the width of the containing block

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("elemID").style.height = 
Math.round((document.getElementById("elemID").style.width * 100) / 35) + "px";
```

This will get a percentage (Rounded) of the with, and assign it to the height.

Comment: you need this slash `/` to divide (i always forget which is called  which =))

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a tablet and got confused :)